# Indy message with Unicode Subject

Tags: delphi, unicode, indy

I need to create a IdMessage with Unicode subject (eg "本語 - test")

I have tried setting it using

```
Msg.Subject := UTF8Encode(subject);
```

where subject is a WideString containing the text above
but when I look at the encoded subject (by saving the Message to file) it looks like this:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=C3=A6=C5=93=C2=AC=C3=A8=C2=AA=C5=BE?= - test
```

instead of

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=E6=0C=AC=E8=AA=9E?= - test
```

and Outlook displays it as "æœ¬èªž - test"

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong?

Delphi 2006 (pre-unicode), Indy 10 (fairly recent from source)

Answer (score 6):

In pre-Unicode versions of Delphi, where everything is based on `AnsiString`, the value you assign to the `TIdMessage.Subject` property (and any other `AnsiString` property of `TIdMessage`, for that matter) *MUST* be encoded using the OS default character encoding.  You are encoding it to UTF-8 instead, which will not work.  This is because `TIdMessage` will first decode the `Subject` value to Unicode using the OS default encoding, then MIME-encode the Unicode data using the encoding parameters provided by the `TIdMessage.OnInitializeISO` event, or defaults if no event handler is assigned (in this case, those parameters are `CharSet=UTF-8` and `HeaderEncoding=QuotedPrintable`).  `TIdMessage` has no mechanism to allow you to specify the encoding used for any `AnsiString` data you assign to it.  So the only possibility to send a value of `'本語 - test'` with the `Subject` property is to assign your source `WideString` as-is to the property and let the RTL convert the data to `AnsiString` using the OS default encoding:

```
Msg.Subject := subject;
```

However, if the OS does not support the Unicode characters being used, there will be data lost.  There is no avoiding that in this scenario.

The alternative is to set the `Subject` property to a blank string and then use the `TIdMessage.ExtraHeaders` property instead so that you can provide your own header value that will be put into the email as-is.  Using this approach, you can call Indy's `EncodeHeader()` function directly.  In pre-Unicode versions of Delphi, it has an optional `ASrcEncoding` parameter that defaults to the OS default encoding (`TIdMessage` does not currently provide a value for that parameter when encoding headers):

```
uses
  ..., IdCoderHeader;

Msg.Subject := '';
Msg.ExtraHeaders.Values['Subject'] := EncodeHeader(UTF8Encode(subject), '', 'Q', 'UTF-8', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);
```

This way, `EncodeHeader()` will be able to avoid a redundant conversion because it can detect that the source and target character encodings are both UTF-8, and thus just MIME-encode the source UTF-8 data as-is.  Worse case, even if it did not detect the character encodings were the same, it would simply decode the source data to Unicode using UTF-8 and then re-encode it back to UTF-8.  Those are lossless conversions, so no data is lost.

And FYI, the correct encoding for the Unicode characters you have shown would be:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=E6=9C=AC=E8=AA=9E?= - test
```

Not

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?=E6=0C=AC=E8=AA=9E?= - test
```

As you have shown.  Notice the second encoded octet is `9C` instead of `0C`.